# How to bind multiple ids on same event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a style='cursor:pointer'   id='anchor1' onmouseover=fnover(this)>
<a style='cursor:pointer'   id='anchor2' onmouseover=fnover(this)>
<a style='cursor:pointer'   id='anchor3'  onmouseover=fnover(this)>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
fnover(obj){
     $('.dropdown').fadeIn();
}
```

My requirement is, I have multiple ids, but I want to bind id dynamically using jQuery. Whenever you mouseover on anchor tag that particular anchor tag will be *fadeIn* or *fadeOut*.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use a single class instead of several ids?

Comment: In my above code .if i mouseover on only one anchor it will show all fadein..how to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 21):

```
$('#id1,#id2,#id3').on('mouseenter',function(){
   //do stuff on mouse over
});
$('#id1,#id2,#id3').on('mouseleave',function(){
   //do stuff on mouse out
});
```

easier of course if you just give your items a class instead of a separate ids, as they seem to do the same thing...

```
$('.myclass').on('mouseleave',function(){
   //do stuff on mouse out
});
```

Comment: But the OP want to bind ID dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this

```
<a style='cursor:pointer' id='anchor1' />
<a style='cursor:pointer' id='anchor2' />
<a style='cursor:pointer' id='anchor3' />
```

and then bind the same functionality to all three anchors

```
$('#anchor1, #anchor2, #anchor3').hover(function(){ //Select all three
    $('.dropdown').fadeIn();                        //On mouse over
}, function(){
    $('.dropdown').fadeOut();                       //on mouse out
});
```

although this code would be better written by giving all the anchor tags you wish to attach this functionality to a class like `aFade` and then selecting them using

```
$('.aFade').hover(function.........
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple selector, separated by comma like

```
$( "#anchor1, #anchor2, #anchor3" ).mouseover(function() {
  $('.dropdown').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 onmouseover=fnover($(this).attr("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class to each HTML element and use the getElementByClass() function to select the elements that you want to use the fadeIn() and fadeOut() on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this if you have some common name for anchor tag id's

```
$(function(){
    $("a[id*=anchor]").mouseover(function(){
       //do your stuff here 
    });
});
```

The above script states that if any anchor tag whose id starts with `anchor`, then the event will be wired up. You don't even have to specify all the id's of the anchor tag.

Its also better if you have some common `.classname` for your anchor tags. So that only that particular class names will wireup the events.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79d7k/1/)**

Hope it helps